# Reduction of carbonyl group

Tags: organic-reduction

A compound contains both alpha,beta unsaturated carbonyl group and a normal carbonyl group. Is there any method to reduce the normal carbonyl group keeping the alpha,beta unsaturated carbonyl group intact?

Comment: Most methods I can think of  e.g. Borohydrides, LiAlH4, Zn/HCl, Wolff-Kishner will reduce both unless there are features of the molecule  (eg steric hindrance) that make one less reactive.

Comment: Look [selective Reduction here](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4039(00)80137-9).